# Join three table to get loan amount,employee total attendance and salary

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, join

I was trying to join these three tables: 
[image: attendance] 
![approved_loan][2]
[image: employee]

I managed to join `Employee` and `Attendance` table easily but can't make it work for the third table. Here is my code to join the two table:

`Approved_leave` table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `approved_leave` (
`id` int(255) NOT NULL,
`company` varchar(70) NOT NULL,
`branch` varchar(70) NOT NULL,
`dept` varchar(70) NOT NULL,
`emp_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`leave_type` varchar(70) NOT NULL,
`day_number` varchar(70) NOT NULL,
`reason` varchar(70) NOT NULL,
`applied_date` date NOT NULL,
 `file` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
`approved_date` date NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

`Attendance` table:

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `attendance` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`company` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`branch` varchar(55) NOT NULL,
`dept` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`employee_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT 
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE        CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`status` varchar(12) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

`Employee` table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `employee` (
`emp_id` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`emp_name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
`emp_contact` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
`com_address` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
`per_address` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
`com_phone` varchar(13) NOT NULL,
`com_email` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`empid` int(20) NOT NULL,
`emp_company` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`emp_branch` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`emp_dept` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`emp_designation` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`emp_salary` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
`emp_type` varchar(10  NOT NULL,
`last_updated` date NOT NULL,
`active` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

$this->db->select('COUNT(status),emp_name,employee_id,emp_salary')
->from('attendance a')->where('dept',$dept_id)
->join('employee e','a.employee_id=e.empid','left')->group_by('employee_id')
->get()->result();
```

approved table column are  written below. My goal is get loan amount of the employee if he has:
`id, loan_amount, reason, employee_id, dept, branch, company applied_date`

Comment: The second table image is missing.

Comment: i am allowed to post only 2 image so i added the column name on the last line please check

Comment: It'll be nice if you update the question with `CREATE TABLE`mysql  query of these 3 tables. Your question has no fields related to `approved_loan` table.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below mysql query:

```
$this->db->select('al.loan_amount,e.emp_name,a.employee_id,e.emp_salary')
->from('attendance a')->where('dept',$dept_id)
->join('employee e','a.employee_id=e.empid')
->join('approved_leave al','al.employee_id=e.empid')
->get()->result();
```

Comment: sorry it shows error while i test this on my database: $this->db->select('al.loan_amount,e.emp_name,a.employee_id,e.emp_salary')
->from('attendance a')->where('dept',1)
->join('employee e','a.employee_id=e.empid','left')
->join('approved_leave al','al.employee_id=e.empid','left')
->get()->result();

Comment: ERROR: Unknown Punctuation String @ 6
STR: ->
SQL: $this->db->select('al.loan_amount,e.emp_name,a.employee_id,e.emp_salary') ->from('attendance a')->where('dept',1) ->join('employee e','a.employee_id=e.empid','left') ->join('approved_leave al','al.employee_id=e.empid','left') ->get()->result()

Comment: i can get loan amount,salary by using:$this->db->select('emp_name,emp_id,emp_salary,amount')->from('employee e')->where( array('emp_company' => $com_id,'emp_branch'=>$branch_id,'emp_dept'=>$dept_id,'active'=>1))->join('approved_loan l','e.empid=l.employee_id','left')->get()->result_array(); but i want total attendance of each employee too @Sankar V